# Wordpress 2017 Theme: Add A Div over the Header image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Being new to Wordpress, and to the way their themes work in general, I have been having a few issues regarding the header section.

With lots of troubleshooting I have fixed most of my programs, but one seems to keep managing to allude me, and that is putting a div at the top of the page, in front of the header image.

Essentially, the header image seems to act as always up front when it comes to anything in the header.php files. I have looked around both here and the site, but I cannot find anything to cure this ailment.

I started by removing the header image entirely, and inserting my code into the custom-header.php file

```
<div class="whatever"><img src="whatever i put here"> | <p>words</p></div>
```

At first, this worked and everything showed up directly as the top as I wanted it, however, once I reinstated the image, it once again filled the entire header and send the divs behind it.

Does anyone know of a way to move this Div to the foreground?

Comment: Try making use of the CSS `z-index` property

Comment: Have already unfortunately. It seems Z-Axis still locks it behind the image no matter what I set it to.

Comment: And you understand [block formatting contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little `css` you can achieve that.
First, I would suggest to use an id for this additional <div> element, as most probably this will be some kind of special tag.
I assume that you were trying to place this div before the `<header id="masthead" …` part in the *header.php* of the 2017 Theme like so:

```
// Existing code …
<div id="whatever"><img src="whatever"> | <p>words</p></div>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
// Existing code …
```

Having that in place, you can bring that div into front with some lines of css:

```
#whatever {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You can place that anywhere in you *style.css*.

Comment: Thanks! With the absolute, it allowed the z-index to work! Thank you very much

Comment: `position: absolute` is a reliable way to create a new block formatting context!